# Install libsystemd-dev on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies

I'm trying to install libsystemd-dev, but having trouble with its dependency.

```
libsystemd-dev : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 237-3ubuntu10.53) but 237-3ubuntu10.54 is to be installed
```

Server: Ubuntu 18.04.6 (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1084-aws x86_64)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get apt-get to ignore some dependencies?](https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies)

Comment: Most likely your libsystemd0 package is pinned to a specific version or you may simply need to apt update to also upgrade that package. Don't ignore the dependency.

Comment: I have done; update, upgrade and dist-upgrade. This error is the same after all these.

Comment: Also, i found this: Version '10.53' for 'libsystemd0' was not found, from sudo apt-get install libsystemd0=10.53